# Android : How to find owner of the Facebook app id?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

This may be a duplicate question but those answers not helped me.

Is it possible to retrieve owner of the Facebook app id?

Please help me to come out from this issue. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I tried with Graph API(https://graph.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx), but it returns only active users list, logo url etc.. not return owner Facebook ID.

**Owner id**: Facebook id where I added myapp

Comment: What is an "owner id"? Do you mean user_id? Please rephrase your question...

Comment: ....and please tell us what you have tried so far. do some research before asking.

Comment: Sorry, but this is still not understandable. In my words: You have an app_id, and want to find out which user created it?

Comment: @AristoMichael Sorry, but that's not possible with the Graph API currently. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can request

```
/{app_id}?fields=id,name,roles&access_token={app_access_token}
```

to receive a list of administrators of the app. But only if you have an App Access Token of the same app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/roles/

Answer (score -1):

First setup your project with facebook sdk. Follow this offical link to setup Facebook SDK.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3

@Override
public View onCreateView(
        LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.splash, container, false);

```
loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends");
// If using in a fragment
loginButton.setFragment(this);    
// Other app specific specialization

// Callback registration
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        // App code
        // your code here
        fetchProfileForCurrentAccessToken();
        getCurrentProfile().getId(); //this is your profile id
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // App code
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
        // App code
    }
});
```

}

Comment: my question is not about get user id. Please check my question once

Comment: no way, facebook won't provide you app owner's facebook id, until and unless you are part of that app.